# How to insert default data into table using import.sql file in Hibernate, MySQL Application

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, import

I am developing an application using Spring MVC (version 3.1), Hibernate (Version 3.5) and MySQL. In this application, I am creating a database schema each time when the application runs. I want to insert some default data into a few tables using import.sql script file. For this I have created import.sql script in the root and using the following statements in hibernate. cfg. xml file.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">import.sql</property>
<property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>
```

But I am not getting success to insert default data into tables.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring must know where to find your file.

If you are using maven, there are several way of doing so.

you can use classpath:/import.sql and put your file in src/test/resources or src/main/resources, depending if you need this for test only or not.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. Actually I was not placing import.sql file in src/main/resources. Now it is working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you! After 2h searching, this really helped me!