# hbm2ddl not working with mysql maven spring hibernate for sql file

Tags: sql, hibernate, maven

I want to populate the DB with some data.

I have the sql script for that.
No matter where I put the `import1.sql` file like.

- `src/main/resources/scripts/import1.sql`
- `src/main/resources/import1.sql`

It is not getting worked as I have also intentionally putted some wrong statements to confirm it is imported or not.

> I already verified the script on the generated schema and it is all fine.
>
> Note: Hibernate configuration like:-

```
 <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">import1.sql</prop>`

               OR
```

`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">src/main/resources/scripts/import1.sql</prop>`

```
               OR
```

`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">src/main/resources/import1.sql</prop>`

```
               OR
```

`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/import1.sql</prop>`

> Help me out on this ...

Comment: just try using `/resource/import1.sql`, also `resource` or `resources`

Comment: That is `resources` and my settings are according to `resources` only. `src/main/resources` is  a source folder.
>  Also i tried /resources/import1.sql NOT working....

Comment: This link might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577262/how-to-insert-default-data-into-table-using-import-sql-file-in-hibernate-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[​Solved]

> Error was multiline comments in the sql file.

`src/main/resources/scripts/import1.sql`

- here till scripts folder classpath should be set
- and also multiline comments like in java will not work(Silly mistake)
  and cause error while executing the script.

> Things to check:
>
> > 1) `sql` File must be direct child of the `source` folder (i.e in `classpath`)
> >
> > 2) try to avoid the `comments` and `multi-line statements` in `sql Script`.