# If using Spring Boot and hibernate, should I use data.sql or import.sql to import data into my database, and why?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.1, MySQL for our different environments (dev, qc, uat, live, staging). We are using H2 for our tests.

Sprint Boot says you can import data using data.sql

Hibernate seems to look for import.sql

Both work independently, but if I include both, only import.sql seems to run.

So, should I use data.sql or import.sql to import data into my database, and why?

Comment: JPA 2.1 provides a STANDARD persistence property to load data into a database when the EMF is created. Since you tagged this question as JPA I presume you are using it

Answer (score 2):

When you use Spring JDBC use `data.sql`, when you use hibernate use `import.sql`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` to choose file(s), yes, you can import files or a single file to be loaded in MySQL database. My instincts tell me this is a duplicate.

[How to insert default data into table using import.sql file in Hibernate, MySQL Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577262/how-to-insert-default-data-into-table-using-import-sql-file-in-hibernate-mysql)